# .CMD Script to Find & Replace Text in Multiple Files

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, cmd

Programming newbie in a bit of a pickle here. I know next to nothing about .cmd or .bat files or the like, but I'm to understand that .cmd is the way to go for a little project I'm currently undertaking. Basically, I'm looking to distribute a file which, when executed, alters two very specific lines from two individual .ini files located in the same folder as the .cmd file.

For NewGame.ini, I would very much like for the following line to be changed from:

FullHealthLimit = 1000

...to...

FullHealthLimit = 9999

And for NewGameUI.ini, I'd like for the following line to be changed from:

m_PosOffset=(X=25,Y=-99)

...to...

m_PosOffset=(X=-9999,Y=-9999)

That's it. I just need one executable file to perform two -- hopefully -- quite basic tasks. Reason being is that my friends and I are really into modding certain video games, but want to make it much easier to distribute files.

I'll be honest: I've had so much trouble trying to implement solutions from other topics and make it work for my situation (largely because of the presence of an equals sign causing grief) that I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible. I'm at my wits' end, I tells ya! ;)

If anyone could provide the necessary code for me, ready to be plonked into a text file and saved as a .cmd file or whatnot, then I would be eternally grateful. I just want for me and my little circle of chums to be able to distribute our little mods amongst our humble community.

Thank you so much for reading about and hopefully looking into my quandary! I really appreciate any and all help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of code that should do the trick.  I haven't tested it though, so you'll have to give it a try and see what it does -- and then report back if there are any anomalies.  Just place the `Fix.bat` file in the same folder with the two INI files and run it from a `cmd` prompt (from the directory with the files).

### Fix.bat

```
@echo off

for /f "eol= delims=" %%i in (NewGame.ini) do (
  if "%%i"=="FullHealthLimit = 1000" (
    echo FullHealthLimit = 9999>> NewGame2.ini
  ) else (
    echo %%i>> NewGame2.ini
  )
)

echo [Unreal.Game_MaxAmmo]>>NewGame2.ini
echo p_zApplyOffset=true>>NewGame2.ini
echo p_zPosOffset=(X=-500,Y=-333)>>NewGame2.ini

:: Once you know it works, move the '::' from the next line to the first 'ren' line
::del NewGame.ini
ren NewGame.ini OldNewGame.ini
ren NewGame2.ini NewGame.ini

for /f "eol= delims=" %%i in (NewGameUI.ini) do (
  if "%%i"=="m_PosOffset=(X=25,Y=-99)" (
    echo m_PosOffset=^(X=-9999,Y=-9999^)>> NewGameUI2.ini
  ) else (
    echo %%i>> NewGameUI2.ini
  )
)

:: Once you know it works, move the '::' from the next line to the first 'ren' line
::del NewGameUI.ini
ren NewGameUI.ini OldNewGameUI.ini
ren NewGameUI2.ini NewGameUI.ini
```

You can see that it does not alter your original `.ini` files in any way, and that it renames them to `OldNewGame.ini` and `OldNewGamUI.ini` just to be safe.

Comment: Hi James, thank you so much for looking into this for me. It really is a tremendous help. I'll give your code a go now. Just so I'm clear, though, am I to understand that your code will not edit the .ini files mentioned, but will instead create new .ini files with the revised values? If this is the case, how would I go about making the .cmd/.bat script edit the original files, and not simply create new, renamed ones? I only ask because it would make things easier for my community members even they did not have to rename the files with edited code to the original file names.

Comment: You can't modify the original files directly.  You have to create a secondary file and then rename it.  For now (while you test), leave it as-is so that you don't lose your original files in case something goes wrong.  Once you've verified it works, then you can replace the first of each `ren NewGame.ini OldNewGame.ini` with `del NewGame.ini`.  This will delete the old file before it renames the newly created file to the old file name.  I'll edit the code above to reflect the changes.  You just need to move the `::` once you know it all works.

Comment: The code does in fact create new files with the same filenames as the originals, so it is like you are editing the original files.  The only difference is that it is creating a backup of the original file with the prefix `Old` just to be safe while you are testing...

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, James. I am so very grateful for your help. I'm tinkering with your script now and will let you know how I get on. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: James, thank you once again for taking the time to look into this for me. I can confirm that the first part of the code works flawlessly. However, it seems that the section involving 'NewGameUI' isn't functioning as intended. I am quite sure that I have followed your directions as closely as one should, but the script does not appear to be triggering anything for that part. No files are created, edited, replaced or anything. It's very odd, as the first part works wonderfully. I will try it a few more times to make absolutely certain that I have not made any mistakes. Do you see any errors?

Comment: James, I'm not sure if this helps, but I tried altering the execution order of the script, making it so that the part involving 'NewGameUI.ini was executed first. As before, 'NewGameUI.ini' was not edited or in any way affect by your script; however, the 'NewGame.ini' was strangely not affected either. When the order is changed, the script does not appear to function. Is is possible that something should come between the two code sections? And is it also possible that an error might be present in the 'NewGameUI.ini' code? I'm so sorry to cause headaches. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: James, just as one last detail: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the only differences between the two lines that require modification is that 'FullHealthLimit = 1000' has an empty line above it -- a paragraph -- whereas 'm_PosOffset=(X=25,Y=-99)' has another line of code above it: 'm_bApplyOffset=true' - not sure if that helps narrow down the possibilities for error.

Comment: I added a caret (`^`) before a couple of the parenthesis.  I think that will make the second part work.  Give it a try...

Comment: James, that worked wonderfully. Thank you so much. I just need help with one last thing: what sort of code would I need to add to the .bat file to make it add an additional paragraph of text? Specifically:

Comment: [Continued]

[Unreal.Game_MaxAmmo]
p_zApplyOffset=true
p_zPosOffset=(X=-500,Y=-333)

It can be added anywhere in the NewGame.ini file; beginning or end is fine. Thank you so much for your help so far.

Edit: Agh! The code doesn't display on different lines! There should be a line-break after [Unreal.Game_MaxAmmo], p_zApplyOffset=true and p_zPosOffset=(X=-500,Y=-333)

Comment: Look at the revised answer... It adds the 3 new lines to the end of the NewGame.ini file.  FYI - Once the answer is complete, it is appreciated if you mark the answer correct, and if it was really helpful, an up-vote is also nice.

Comment: Thank you James, I will upvote your responses now. I am new to StackOverlow and still learning my way around, so please do not think I was ungrateful. I have one last question: how do I make it so that .bat file can seek out -- and prepare to replace -- a multi-line section of text? The adding multi-line text strings part is perfect, thanks to you, but I now need the file to be able to seek out a larger, multi-line paragraph and replace it with another multi-line section of text, for the sake of specificity, as there are sections of the file which are identical and require additional details.

Comment: Just to clarify, by 'seeking out' multi-line sections of text I meant something like this: I'd like for the .bat file to be able to find the following section of text "[FullScreenMovie] [new line] +StartupVideo=Attack [new line] ;+StartupMusic=01.mp3 [new line] +StartupSkip=false" And replace it with the code of my choosing, likely another multi-line section of code. Please let me know if this would be possible. Thank you so much for your help so far, James.

Comment: To replace multiple lines in a section of an INI file, you really have moved past the capabilities of .bat files.  It would be better to write a program that communicates with a Windows INI file, and can therefore use the Windows API to locate and alter entries within a given section.

Comment: Google: 'command line edit windows ini file', find tools like: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/IniFile.shtml