# Add text between two lines using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have 1000 files.
The files have the following format

```
>.
>.
>.
>Line-X
>Line-Y
>.
>.
>.
```

I want to search for Line-X and insert Line-Z between X and Y.
I want to use .bat files for doing the same.
Any ideas. I am absolute novice to bat files.

Comment: _Any ideas_ - Yes, ask google first! `batch find` or `batch insert line`

Comment: You could use the approach in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895575/cmd-script-to-find-replace-text-in-multiple-files/14901891#14901891) to find the line, and instead of replacing a line, you could search for Line-X and then after you insert Line-X, you could insert Line-Z as well before it loop to the next line...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to batch files, here's something to help get you started.  It doesn't modify the original files, but it does create new files with the modifications...

If you have three text files (x.txt, y.txt, and z.txt) with the contents you listed above, and you run this batch file from the same folder with the three files, then this batch file creates three new files (x.txt2, y.txt2, and z.txt2) with the the same contents -- only it also has `>Line-Z` between the X and Y lines:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  for /f "eol= delims=" %%v in (%%f) do (
    if "%%v"==">Line-X" (
      echo %%v>> %%f2
      echo ^>Line-Z>> %%f2
    ) else (
      echo %%v>> %%f2
    )
  )
)
```